# SFTP download from terminal is fine, via script not working

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sftp

I am writing a backup script which will download all backups begins with hostname f.e MikroTik which is contained in variable device. When I put command in terminal it will download all files I need, but when I put it tot script, then it show me message file Mikrotik not found.

Here is the code sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="admin"
address="IP"
#command will get devcie hostname in complex form 
ssh $user@$address '/system identity print interval=' > devices

#will get device hostname
tmpDevices=$(cat devices)

device=$(echo $tmpDevices | awk ' {print $2} ')
echo "Device hostname is $device"

echo "Connecting to device via SFTP and downloading files"
#sftp "${user}@${address}:/${device}*"
sftp $user@$address:$device*
```

Here is the output:

```
Device hostname is MikroTik
MikroTik
Connecting to device via SFTP and downloading files
Connected to 10.120.0.253.
File "/MikroTik" not found.
```

Can you please advice me.

Adrian.

Comment: What is `/system`?  Does there exist a file/directory on `10.120.0.253` with a directory off root that starts with the hostname?  The error `File "/MikroTik" not found.` seems self-explanatory.

Comment: It is on mikrotik so i tried with / or without and no success

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.  Do there exist files in the root directory on that host that begin with `MikoTik`?

Comment: yeah there is just root filesystem /

Comment: Please add the output of the following command to your question above:  `ssh ${user}@${address} "ls /MikroTik*"`.  Fill in user/address appropriately.

Comment: here is the output: adrian@adrian-ThinkPad-X230:~/Desktop/zaloha$ ./zalohuj.sh 
Device hostname is MikroTik
pub
skins
MikroTik_dec07log.txt
MikroTik_dec07backup.backup
MikroTik_dec07export.rsc

Comment: "add .. to your questions above" (i.e., not as a comment).

Comment: .. adrian@adrian-ThinkPad-X230:~/Desktop/zaloha$ ./zalohuj.sh Device hostname is MikroTik pub skins MikroTik_dec07log.txt MikroTik_dec07backup.backup MikroTik_dec07export.rsc –

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using scp instead of sftp.  Assuming that you want to copy files from the root directory on the remote host to the current directory on the local host:

```
scp "${user}@${address}:/${device}*" .
```

For example, I've created the following files on a remote host:

```
$ ssh user@remoteHost "ls /MikroTik*"
/MikroTik_dec07backup.backup
/MikroTik_dec07export.rsc
/MikroTik_dec07log.txt
```

From my local host, I can do:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/example
$ cd /tmp/example
$ scp "user@remoteHost:/MikroTik*" .
MikroTik_dec07backup.backup                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
MikroTik_dec07export.rsc                      100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
MikroTik_dec07log.txt                         100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
$ ls
MikroTik_dec07backup.backup  MikroTik_dec07export.rsc  MikroTik_dec07log.txt
$
```

Comment: no success with that also, no file found but the files are there

Comment: Did you include the quotes as specified?

Comment: I was battling with this 4 hours yesterday nothing worked

Comment: Again, you didn't answer my question.  When someone asks a question, that generally means that they need additional information in order to move forward.

Comment: yeah, i tried it as said, no file found also from terminal with proper parameters it was impossible to download them, no luck there mate

Comment: response is with the same as you used: scp error: /MikroTik*: no such file or directory! (They are there as I mentioned milion times there)

Answer (score -1):

```
adrian@adrian-ThinkPad-X230:~/Desktop/zaloha$ sftp admin@IP:/MikroTik*
Connected to IP.
Fetching /MikroTik_dec07backup.backup to MikroTik_dec07backup.backup
/MikroTik_dec07backup.backup                                                                                                                                                  100%   10KB  10.5KB/s   00:00    
Fetching /MikroTik_dec07export.rsc to MikroTik_dec07export.rsc
/MikroTik_dec07export.rsc                                                                                                                                                     100%  329     0.3KB/s   00:00    
Fetching /MikroTik_dec07log.txt to MikroTik_dec07log.txt
/MikroTik_dec07log.txt                                                                                                                                                        100%   75KB  75.1KB/s   00:00
```

When I use it ion script as :

```
#!/bin/bash
user="admin"
address="IP"
#command will get devcie hostname in complex form 
ssh $user@$address '/system identity print interval=' > devices

#will get device hostname
tmpDevices=$(cat devices)

device=$(echo $tmpDevices | awk ' {print $2} ')
echo "Device hostname is $device"

echo "Connecting to device via SFTP and downloading files"
#sftp "${user}@${address}:/${device}*"
sftp $user@$address:$device*
```

Output is:

```
Connecting to device via SFTP and downloading files
Connected to address.
File "/MikroTik" not found.
```

Comment: Not sure why you copied your question as an answer?

Comment: I think this should be an [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/409497/edit) to your question...

Comment: wanna help me or not? I am trying to get answers and your response is what I found on google guys and nothing helped